# Locate WhatsApp message destination

Tags: wireshark, whatsapp

I've been interested in message tracing, so I played a bit with Cisco's Packet Tracer and Wireshark.

Is it possible to locate the destination IP of a message (packages) been sent via WhatsApp? I am not trying to read data out of the packages, I just wonder if it is possible to trace the destination location of the message which has been received.

Comment: How do you determine which message without being able to read at least the metadata of the message so that you know which one you are tracing?

Comment: As the answer below and the duplicate explains, it's not a point-to-point connection. It goes through a server.

Answer (score 2):

The backbone of WhatsApp works like a client/server architecture which is actually based on [XMPP(Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol)](https://xmpp.org/uses/instant-messaging.html), where clients do not transact directly with one another.

However, it is possible for WhatsApp calls to reveal one's IP address, as calls connect in a P2P manner and not through a 'middle-man'!

Comment: thanks mallocation! i didnt know that. So it is indeed impossible to geolocate the destination of messages beeing delivered ?

Comment: Yeah, unless you have logs of the server, if not I don't see how!